# How to add Id to "QDomElement" tags in kml file using Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, tags, kml

I am trying to add ids to the QDomElements in cpp. I successfully genearte a kml file. I want to add the ids to the kml tags like Document, Placemark in incremental way. How can I add ids to the tags in kml file.

```
    QDomProcessingInstruction header = createProcessingInstruction(QStringLiteral("xml"), QStringLiteral("version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\""));
    appendChild(header);

    QDomElement kmlElement = createElement(QStringLiteral("kml"));
    kmlElement.setAttribute(QStringLiteral("xmlns"), "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
   
    QDomElement m_rootDocumentElement;  m_rootDocumentElement = 
    createElement(QStringLiteral("Document"));
    kmlElement.appendChild(m_rootDocumentElement);
    for(int i = 0; i < qgeoCordinateList.count(); i++){
         QDomElement wpPlacemarkElement = createElement("Placemark");
       QDomElement wpPlacemarkElement1 = elementById("4");
        m_rootDocumentElement.appendChild(wpPlacemarkElement);
        wpPlacemarkElement.appendChild(wpPlacemarkElement1);
        addTextElement(wpPlacemarkElement, "name", QString::number(i+1));
        QDomElement pointElement = createElement("Point");
        wpPlacemarkElement.appendChild(pointElement);
        addTextElement(pointElement, "Index", QString::number(i));
    }

    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << header;
    stream << kmlElement;
    qDebug() << "kml Data :" << kmlElement.toElement().text().simplified();
    file.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To add Id into "QDomElement" tag add line where you want to add tag for QDomElement 
 
  wpPlacemarkElement.setAttribute(QStringLiteral("id"), QString::number(i)); 

// i is index of for loop
// add this line into for loop
```